# Import custom React component into Markdown in GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, markdown, gatsby

**In GatsbyJS, when authoring a markdown file, how can I import and display a custom React component?**

I am using the official [gatsby-starter-blog](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/) starter which comes with markdown support. It works great for blog posts. However, I would now like to add a custom React component into my markdown file. What do I need to do to achieve this?

Here is my attempt. No errors, but the custom component tag does not get converted into the actual React component.

**post-1\index.md:**

```
---
title: My first post
date: "2000-01-01"
description: Wouldn't it be sweet if there was a custom React component in here?
---

import CustomComponent from '../../../src/components/CustomComponent.js'

Lorem ipsum dolor.

<CustomComponent title="Test" />
```

Folder structure:

```
content
- blog
-- post-1
---- index.md
src
- components
-- CustomComponent.js
```

Comment: Check out https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/mdx/. Markdown doesn't support JSX.

Comment: But how does that combine with the Markdown parser that comes out of the box with the official blog starter?

Comment: Out of the box, It doesn't. Try something like https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/hagnerd/gatsby-starter-blog-mdx/ or https://github.com/ChristopherBiscardi/gatsby-starter-mdx-basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown doesn't support JSX. You can use MDX for this. Gatsby has extensive documentation & official plugin for supporting the feature. You can read more at: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/mdx/

MDX will allow you to have MD files looking like:

```
import { Chart } from '../components/chart'

The chart is rendered inside our MDX document.

<Chart />
```

Which you can in turn use in your Gatsby app like this:

```js
import React from "react"
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react"
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"
import mdxContent from "./your-content.mdx"

export default () => {
    return (
        <MDXProvider>
            <MDXRenderer>{mdxContent}</MDXRenderer>
        </MDXProvider>
    )
}
```